# SQL Server group by 2 columns - generate sequence number

Tags: sql-server

I have table like below,

```
create table #temp
(
    Name varchar(100),
    Id int,
)

Insert into #temp values ('AAA',101)
Insert into #temp values ('AAA',102)
Insert into #temp values ('AAA',102)
Insert into #temp values ('AAA',103)
Insert into #temp values ('AAA',103)
Insert into #temp values ('BBB',201)
Insert into #temp values ('BBB',201)
Insert into #temp values ('BBB',202)
Insert into #temp values ('BBB',203)
```

Expected output:

```
Name  Id      Seq 
-------------------
AAA   101      1
AAA   102      2
AAA   102      2
AAA   103      3
AAA   103      3
BBB   201      1
BBB   201      1
BBB   202      2
BBB   203      3
```

I want to generate sequence number based on name and Id. If Id is same, same sequence number needs to be assign.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Id,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Id) Seq
FROM #temp;
```

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo